# Roots of polynomial outside a vertical strip of $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Let $P(z)$ be an arbitrary polynomial with real coefficients. I'd like to guarantee that all roots of $P$ have real parts outside the interval $(0, 1)$. Is there some simple condition on *P* that will ensure that?

Let me illustrate further. If $P$ were known to only have real roots, a simple condition would (almost tautologically) be “P does not change sign on $(0, 1)$”. For the general case that $P$ has complex roots, is there some condition that will guarantee that no root $z_i$ satisfies $0 < \mathrm{Re}\, z_i < 1$?

Note that I'm looking for a sufficient condition. That is, I don't need to characterize the class of all polynomials that fulfill the stated condition; a “reasonably” large subclass of that class may be enough for me.

Comment: You might take a look at Rouche's Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9's_theorem

Comment: @AlexS Thanks, I will!

Answer (score 3):

This is a nontrivial task, and the best approach may depend on how the polynomial is specified (i.e., what kind of structure it has). In principle, the [Routh–Hurwitz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_theorem) can answer the question, as it gives the number of roots in the positive half plane $\{z:\operatorname{Re}z>0\}$. Your problem amounts to determining whether this number is the same for $P$ and for $P(z+1)$.

The related [Routh–Hurwitz stability criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion) is easier to check in practice, and provides a sufficient condition: if the criterion holds, there are no roots with positive real part, and in particular with real part between $0$ and $1$.

Finally, since Alex S mentioned Rouché's theorem, I'll point to the post [How many roots of a polynomial have positive real part?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80839/how-many-roots-of-a-polynomial-have-positive-real-part) for an example of its usage in this context.

Comment: Thanks! I also thought about Hurwitz polynomials. However, they seem too restrictive, because if I'm correct a Hurwitz polynomial with real coefficients must hace all its coefficients positive. That rules out many Taylor polynomials (truncated Taylor series), which is the application I had in mind. On the other hand, this might be the best one can get. I'll wait for a while in case other answers appear